# League system and Elo rating system

Tags: league-of-legends

When I was reading about LoL I found also lots of information about about Elo hell. But [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_system) I read that after season 3 elo system was replaced by other system. I have two questions:

1. Does the elo hell still exists? I mean, does the new system still have something similar to elo hell?
2. Is there any situation that you need to create new account because it is too hard to get to upper division with old account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Does Elo Hell still exist?**

No, because it never did. 'Elo Hell' is a term used when a player believes that their rating is far superior to where they are being placed, but they cannot win due to their teammates poor play. Even now, it is heavily agreed that the Elo system is still used behind the scenes. The 'Elo' system is complex, but you should always get matched with those around your skill level. If you get unlucky, or play poorly, you may not be able to win several times in a row, but eventually the opponents will be under your actual level and you will be able to win and or carry your team. This is why you often see downward or upward trends in your games. If you really think you are in ELO hell, you should focus on improving your play; if you are not a leaver/feeder/weak-point in the game, then your opponents have a better statistical chance of having a leaver/feeder/weak-point on their team.

**Is there any situation where you need to create a new account because it is too hard to get to an upper division with an old account?**

This is a very VERY unlikely scenario. The only way this is feasible is if you were quite bad and rated appropriately. Then, you decide to take a break from ranked and improve your play **drastically**. In such a case, it may take less games to level a new account to 30 and get a new ranking than to work your way out of the lower division. I would say 99.9% of the time this is not the case, however. The easiest way is definitely to keep playing on existing accounts - as you will eventually get placed at (or very close to) your skill level.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real ELO hell if you think about it.

**What do players consider the "ELO hell"?**

At some point your own ELO rating would (could?) be so low you'd pretty much always play with teammates that are - in short - too dumb to play the game. So you'd lose every match, there'd be no way to raise your rating anymore.

**Why it's a non-issue:**

While this sounds quite serious, it can't be that bad if you think about it.

The pool of similar rated players doesn't only fill your own team. The enemies are picked from those as well!

---

So even if the other players on your "tier" are literally too stupid to even move their champion off the summoner platform, so will your enemies.

If you're really better than all of them, you should be able to carry your team to victory. And even if that's not the case, the chances are still like 50:50 winning or losing. It's not like the game magically puts you in a "ELO hell team" vs. a team of better players. While that might happen, it's still very unlikely.

And even then, you don't have to play on your own tier. Play with some buddy who's got a higher rating and you'll play with/against other players of a higher rating (not as high as your buddy).

Comment: I think of ELO hell more as the low area where you're not playing with anyone much better than you (because there are a lot of people at about the same skill level at the low end).  This means that there's no one to learn from in-game - thus why people get stuck there.  On the other hand, once you hit high silver/low gold you play against a bigger range and have teammates/opponents you can really learn from.

Comment: The player pool is most likely bigger, true, and it can be hard to learn from, but the teams aren't as onesided as peopel sometimes claim. And even if you don't learn anything, your chances to win are as likely as they are in higher tiers, unless you're indeed so bad that you're losing every game, but even then you can't blame *ELO hell*.